# Proof of Linear Homogenous Recurrence Relations with constant coefficient and with two distinct roots

Tags: recurrence-relations

I was going through the book "Discrete Mathematics and its Application" by Kenneth Rosen where I came across the proof the following theorem. The backward proof is fine but I did not feel the forward proof of quite satisfactory.

> Theorem: Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be real numbers. Suppose that $r^{2} − c_1r−c_2=0$ has two distinct roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ . Then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation $a_n = c_1 a_{n−1} + c_2 a_{n−2}$ if and only if $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ for $n = 0, 1, 2,...,$ where $α_1$ and $α_2$ are constants.

Proof: We must do two things to prove the theorem. First, it must be shown that if $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the characteristic equation, and $α_1$ and $α_2$ are constants, then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation. ***Second, it must be shown that if the sequence $\{a_n \}$ is a solution, then $a_n = c_1 a_{n−1} + c_2 a_{n−2}$ for some constants $α_1$ and $α_2$.***

The forward proof

> Now we will show that if $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ , then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation. Because $r_1$ and $r_2$ are roots of $r^{2} − c_1r−c_2=0$ ,it follows that $r_1^{2}=c_1r_1+c_2$,$r_2^{2}=c_1r_2+c_2$. From these equations, we see that
>
> $$c_1a_{n−1} + c_2a_{n−2}$$
>
> $$= c_1(α_1r_1^{n−1}+α_2r_2^{n−1} )+c_2(α_1r_1^{n−2}+α_2r_2^{n−2})$$
> $$ = α_1r_1^ {n−2}(c_1r_1+c_2)+α_2r_2 ^{n−2}(c_1r_2 + c_2)$$
> $$ = α_1r_1^{n−2}r_1^{2}+α_2r_2^{n−2}r_2^{2}$$
> $$ = α_1r_1^{n} +α_2r_2{n}$$
> $$ = a_n.$$
>
> This shows that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n = α_1 r_1^{n}+α_2r_2^{n}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation.

The backward proof

> To show that every solution $\{a_n\}$ of the recurrence relation $a_n = c_1 a_{n−1} + c_2 a_{n−2}$ has $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ for $n = 0, 1, 2,...$ , for some constants $α_1$ and $α_2$, suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation, and the initial conditions $a_0 = C_0$ and $a_1 = C_1$ hold. **It will be shown that there are constants $α_1$ and $α_2$ such that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ satisfies these same initial conditions.**
>
> This requires that
>
> $a_0=C_0=α_1+α_2$, $a_1=C_1=α_1r_1+α_2r_2$.
>
> We can solve these two equations for α_1 and α_2 . From the first equation it follows that
>
> $α_2 = C_0 − α_1$ .
>
> Inserting this expression into the second equation gives
>
> $C_1=α_1r_1+(C_0−α_1)r_2$.
>
> Hence,
>
> $C_1=α_1(r_1 −r_2)+C_0r_2$.
>
> This shows that
>
> $α_1=\frac{ C_1 − C_0r_2}{r_1−r_2}$
>
> and
>
> $α_2=C_0−α_1=C_0− \frac{C_1 − C_0r_2} {r_1−r_2} = \frac{C_0r_1 − C_1}{ r1−r2}$
>
> , where these expressions for $α_1$ and $α_2$ depend on the fact that $r_1 \neq r_2$ . (When $r_1 = r_2$ , this theorem is not true.) Hence, with these values for $α_1$ and $α_2$ , the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ satisfies the two initial conditions. **We know that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}\}$ are both solutions of the recurrence relation $a_n = c_1 a_{n−1} + c_2 a_{n−2}$ and both satisfy the initial conditions when $n = 0$ and $n = 1$. Because there is a unique solution of a linear homogeneous recurrence relation of degree two with two initial conditions**, it follows that the two solutions are the same, that is, $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ for all nonnegative integers $n$.

---

**Doubts**

In the forward part we are supposed to prove something of the form,

if "$\{a_n\}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation" $=>$ "$\{a_n\}$ is same as  $\{α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}\}$".

---

Here in the above forward proof, for the purpose below,

> It will be shown that there are constants $α_1$ and $α_2$ such that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n =α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}$ satisfies these same initial conditions.

we are sort of using the conclusion of the above implication to show the conclusion is true if the hypothesis is true.

---

> We know that $\{a_n\}$ and $\{α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}\}$ are both solutions of the recurrence relation $a_n = c_1 a_{n−1} + c_2 a_{n−2}$

I hope they are using the proof of the first part (backward proof) to say that $\{α_1r^{n} +α_2r^{n}\}$ is a solution of the recurrence relation.

---

> Because there is a unique solution of a linear homogeneous recurrence relation of degree two with two initial conditions

I hope the above is theorem which exists and it is not dealt with in the book.

---

The entire forward proof for seems a bit weird to me and it seems that was sort of forcely made to agree the facts of mathematics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446567/understanding-linear-recurrence-theorem                                                                                                                                                     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475334/proving-theorem-regarding-lhrcc-linear-homogenous-recurrence-relations-with-tw?rq=1                                                      my question might seem similar but it is different from the above two

Answer (score 3):

Alternative proof:
Let $U$ be the set of sequences and $A_m : U \mapsto \mathbb{R}$
be defined as
$$A_m((u_n)_n) := u_{m+2} -c_1 u_{m+1} - c_2 u_m.$$
Then it is easy to check that A_m is linear.  One also checks that $(r_i^n)_n$ satisfies $A_m((r_i^n)_n) = 0$ for all $m \ge 0$ and $i= 1,2$.  It follows that $A_m((\alpha_1 r_1^n + \alpha_2 r_2^n)_n) = 0$ for all $m \ge 0$.

One obtains uniqueness of solutions if $u_0 = C_0$ and $u_1 = C_1$ by contradiction: suppose there were two solutions $(u_n)_n$ and $(v_n)_n$.  Let $m$ be the smallest number such that $u_m \neq v_m$.  The recurrence relation leads to a contradiction.

Now suppose $C_0$ and $C_1$ are given.  We must check that there are $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ such that
$$ \alpha_1 r_1^0 + \alpha_2 r_2^0 = C_0$$ and
$$ \alpha_1 r_1^1 + \alpha_2 r_2^1 = C_1$$.
Such $alpha_i$ can be found if the determinant of the matrix of the system is nonzero.  One computes the determinant: $r_2 - r_1 \neq 0$ since $r_1 \neq r_2$.