# second order linear homogeneous recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding second-order linear homogenous recurrence relations. The notes I have been given really are not helping me understand the process as they are written for mathematics students (which I am not) so there is a lot of assumed knowledge that is just left out.
I was wondering if someone could explain how I would solve this problem step by step

$a_n = −4a_{n−1} − 4a_{n−2}$ for all integers $n ≥ 2$ with $a_0 = 0$, and $a_1 = −1$

Comment: See also [Proof for the formula of the $n^\text{th}$ term of a linear and homogeneous second-order recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198351/proof-for-the-formula-of-the-n-textth-term-of-a-linear-and-homogeneous-seco/).

Comment: @dxiv And see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4247104.

Comment: @CMC.V I don't think you meant the link to point to the very question here.

Comment: Since you have "notes", which parts of the notes don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Solving linear recurrence equations is similar to solving linear differential equations.
$$a_n = −4a_{n−1} − 4a_{n−2}$$

$$ a_n= b^n \implies  b^2+4b+4=0$$
$$b=-2,-2$$

Thus the solution is $$a_n = A (-2)^n + B n(-2)^n $$

The coefficients A and B are found from the initial conditions.
For $n=0$, we get $A=0$ and for $n=1$ we get $-2B=-1$, thus $B=1/2$

The solution is $$ a_n = (-1)^n n 2^{n-1}$$