# How would you vaticinate to subtract $w_k$ from both sides of $w_{k + 1} = \frac{w_k - (1 - p)w_{k - 1}}{p}$?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

This question appeared on my pop quiz. I got 0%. I achieved everything until the green equation, then I didn't know how to proceed. After reading this solution, I see that you must isolate $pw_{k + 1}$ and move $w_k$
to the right.

$$\color{limegreen}{w_k = pw_{k + 1} + (1- p)w_{k - 1}} \iff pw_{k + 1} = w_k - (1 - p)w_{k - 1}$$

1. Then you must divide the equation by p.

$$w_{k + 1} = \dfrac{w_k - (1 - p)w_{k - 1}}{p}$$

2. Finally, you must subtract ${\color{red}{w_k}}$ from both sides!

$$w_{k + 1} -{\color{red}{w_k}} = \dfrac{1\color{red}{-p}}{p}(w_k - w_{k - 1})$$

These steps eluded me and came out of the blue!  How would you prognosticate this tricky algebra?

[image: Image alt text]

Tsitsiklis, *Introduction to Probability* (2008 2e), p 63.

Comment: The idea is to find a suitable $\lambda$ such that $w_{k+1}-\lambda w_k$ is a geometric progression., whose general expression you know already - see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198621/291201) for more details. That's assuming you don't know (or don't want to use) the characteristic polynomial of the [linear homogeneous recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) to solve it directly.

Comment: Because of experience I thought of subtracting $w_{k-1},$ giving $w_{k+1} -w_{k-1}=.(w_k- w_{k-1})/p,$ which looks promising . It looks even better when you substitute $f_k=w_k- w_{k-1}$  as it gives $f_k/p= w_{k+1}- w_{k-1}=( w_{k+1}-w_k)+(w_k- w_{k-1})=f_{k+1}+f_k.$