# Binet's formula of Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

In an attempt to find the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number by **Binet's formula**, the derivation of this formula starts by using the quadratic equation

$$x^2-x-1 = 0$$

If we try to find roots of this equation using quadratic roots formula, we find that we have 2 roots:

$$ \sigma = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}, \gamma= \frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}$$

Then, we notice that:

\begin{align}
x^2 = x+1 \\
x^3 = 2x+1 \\
\vdots\\
x^6 = 8x+5 \\
\vdots\\
\end{align}

**Question**: why do we start with $x^2-x-1 = 0$ specifically and not with others? Is it because it just fulfill the need?

Comment: Do you see the similarity between $x^2 = x+1 = x^1+x^0$ and $f_2 = f_1+f_0$?

Comment: You have to study the little theory about recurrent sequences of the second order and the fact that they constitute a vector space with dimension two with basis $e^{na}$ and $e^{nb}$ where $a,b$ are the roots (assume distinct, as is the case here) of the characteristic **quadratic** equation you have considered.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thanks Prof.

Comment: @Avv See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198621/291201) which describes an elementary, self-contained way to solve second order recurrences, without assuming prior knowledge of characteristic polynomials or any of the theory behind.