# I was wondering how can we prove that a recurrence relationship depending on the two previous terms is actually the sum of two geometric sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, recurrence-relations

I was working on a problem and I stumbled upon this equality:

$a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_{n}$

And I'm trying to find the general expression of the sequence $a$.

For this, I wanted to show that $a$ can just be expressed as the sum of two geometric sequence so that I can rewrite this equality using the general expression of geometric sequences:

Edit: $q {\neq} 0$

$a_0*q^{n+2} = a_0*q^{n+1} + a_0*q^{n}$

but I didn't manage to prove that.

Could someone help me please

Comment: What should $q$ be for that condition to be true? One condition suffices for all $n$. Can you match any initial conditions using sums of geometric sequences (not series)?

Comment: These are the Fibonacci numbers (possibly with different initial conditions).  They are well documented online.

Comment: yes my bad geometric sequence. And $q {\neq} 0$

Comment: Depends on whether you wish to show that this is possible for any value of $q$,
or instead wish to show that a specific value of $q$ exists, that makes this
formula work.  You would need $q$ to satisfy the equation 
$$q^2 = q + 1.$$

Comment: yes I found this formula. But to prove this what should I write ? As you get this formula by using the general formula of a  geometric sequence. 
Or can I just write that that $a_n$ can be written as a sum of two geometric series, with a q that exist such as $q^2 = q +1$ ?

Comment: @Beni See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198621/291201) for a proof from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

[Second-order linear relations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#General_solution) are very well-documented problems.

In your case, the equation can be rewritten :
$$a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} - a_n = 0$$

You need to study the characteristic polynomial equation $P(X) = X^2 - X - 1 = 0$. This one has two roots: $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}$ and $\bar \varphi = \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2}$. (Note that $\varphi$ is the “golden ratio”.) Then, all the solutions to your recurrence relation are the sequences of form:
$$a_n = A \varphi^n + B \bar\varphi^n$$
with $A, B \in \mathbf R$.

The values of $A$ and $B$ depend on your initial conditions.

Comment: but shouldn't I prove first that $a_n$ can be written as the sum of two geometric sequences ?

Comment: This depends on what you assume and what you want to prove exactly. If you only need to prove that a sequence of form $A\varphi^n + B \bar\varphi^n$ is a solution to the problem, then it is enough to prove that it satisfies the recurrence relation. If you need to prove that these sequences are the only solutions, then [look at my second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657572/565932).

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I prove that it satisfies the recurrence relation though?

Comment: also I didn't really understand where do you get the characteristic polynomial equation from ?

Comment: If $a u_{n+2} + b u_{n+1} + c u_{n} = 0$, then the associated characteristic polynomial is $P(X) = a X^2 + bX + c$. Here, $a = 1$, $b = -1$ and $c = -1$. Concerning the recurrence relation, you can try to adapt the proof of my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b$ be the roots of $$px^2+qx+r=0.....(1)$$
Then
$$pa^2+qa+r=0$$
$$\implies Cpa^{n+2}+Cqa^{n+1}+Cra^n=0$$
Similarly, we have
$$Dpb^{n+2}+Dqb^{n+1}+Drb^n=0$$
Adding these two equations, we get
$$p(C a^{n+2}+D a^{n+2})+q(Ca^{n+1}+Db^{n+1})+r(Ca^n+Db^n)=0.$$
Introduce $$A_n=C a^n+D b^n.....(2)$$ Then we can write
$$pA_{n+2}+qA_{n+1}+rA_n=0.....(3)$$

Finally (2) is the general solution (sum of two GPs) of the recurrence relation (3), where $a,b$ are the roots of (1) and $C,D$ are two arbitrary paramwteres to be determined by the given initial values.

Comment: I didn't really understand where do you get that from: 2++=0

Comment: See p, q, r  occur in the recurrence relation  (3). Use them to get a quadratic it's roots and finally $A_n$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now a solution if you do not assume the theorem about the closed form of recurrent linear sequences of order 2.

Consider any sequence $(u_n)_n$ such that $u_{n+2} = a u_{n +1} + b u_n$. Assume that polynomial $X^2 - a X - b$ has two complex roots $\alpha \neq \beta \in \mathbf C$.

We want to prove that there exists $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbf C$ such that for all $n \in \mathbf N$,
$$ u_n = \lambda \alpha^n + \mu \beta^n$$

**Necessary condition.** For $n = 0$, one needs have $u_0 = \lambda + \mu$. For $n = 1$, one needs have $u_1 = \lambda \alpha + \mu \beta$. As $\alpha \neq \beta$, this system of equations has a single solution:
$$\lambda = \frac{u_1 - \beta u_0}{\alpha - \beta}, \quad \mu = \frac{u_1 - \alpha u_0}{\beta - \alpha}$$

**Sufficient condition.** Now, we need to prove that the sequence:
$$u_n = \lambda \alpha^n + \mu \beta^n$$
with $\lambda = \frac{u_1 - \beta u_0}{\alpha - \beta}$ and $\mu = \frac{u_1 - \alpha u_0}{\beta - \alpha}$
satisfies the recurrence condition. This can be proven by recurrence.

Indeed, the equality is matched for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$. Assume it is matched for some $n$ and for $n+1$. Then, at rank $n+2$:
$$u_{n+2} = a u_{n+1} + b u_n$$
As the equality is assumed for ranks $n$ and $n+1$,
$$u_{n+2} = a (\lambda \alpha^{n+1} + \mu \beta^{n+1}) + b(\lambda \alpha^n + \mu \beta^n)$$
$$u_{n+2} = \lambda \alpha^n (a \alpha + b) + \mu \beta^n (a \beta + b)$$
As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are solutions to $X^2 = aX + b$, we have:
$$u_{n+2} = \lambda \alpha^n \alpha^2 + \mu \beta^n \beta^2$$
$$u_{n+1} = \lambda \alpha^{n+2} + \mu \beta^{n+2}$$

This proves the equality at rank $n+2$. By recurence, for every $n \in \mathbf N$, one has:
$$u_n = \lambda \alpha^n + \mu \beta^n.$$

QED.